# Is it possible to label points in a weighted scatter plot in Stata?

Tags: stata, scatter-plot

For example, the graph for the weighted scatter plot on the official Stata website is:

```
webuse census
scatter death medage [w=pop65p], msymbol(circle_hollow)
```

If I use the *mlabel* option, my points are labelled but are no longer weighted. Is there a way to accomplish both at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overlay two plots:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto
gen somew = _n

twoway scatter price mpg [w=somew], msymbol(circle_hollow) || ///
       scatter price mpg, msymbol(i) mlabel(make) ||, legend(off)
```

The solution is from [Statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-06/msg00277.html). Nick Cox has some "awkward questions" related to the use of such plots, [you might want to read](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-06/msg00291.html).

Comment: Thank you Roberto. The example and the links both offer great insights into Stata.

Comment: Although these plots have a much longer history, perhaps the biggest single recent stimulus to their use has been a presentation by Hans Rosling: http://www.ted.com/talks/hans_rosling_shows_the_best_stats_you_ve_ever_seen Simply, not all similar applications work so well!